# JVM memory stats don't make sense to me

Tags: java, jvm

I'm trying to understand the output of various JVM memory diagnostics. First thing I do,

```
$ jcmd 27263 GC.heap_info
27263:
 garbage-first heap   total 29319168K, used 16150310K [0x00000000c3000000, 0x00000000c3806fd8, 0x00000007c0800000)
  region size 8192K, 1132 young (9273344K), 8 survivors (65536K)
 Metaspace       used 457222K, capacity 526687K, committed 526848K, reserved 1507328K
  class space    used 50629K, capacity 68310K, committed 68352K, reserved 1048576K
```

So the used heap size is 16150310k/(1024^2) = 15.4GB. And now I do:

```
$ jstat -gc 27263
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
 0.0   65536.0  0.0   65536.0 2547712.0 1736704.0 26705920.0 6794156.1  527104.0 457297.5 68352.0 50635.9   1876  212.356   0      0.000  212.356
```

And I add up S1U (S1 survivor space utilization), EU (Eden space utilization), OU (Old gen utilization): 65536.0 + 1736704.0 + 6794156.1 = 8,596,396.1K = 8.2GB.

What am I missing here? Why does Eden + survivor + Old gen ≠ heap?

Comment: In G1, besides eden/survivor/old regions, there are humongous regions. jstat numbers make sense mostly for old-fashioned collectors; with a modern JVM, it's better to use JMX for monitoring.

Comment: @apangin Then I still don't understand. Using JMXTERM I do `get -b java.lang:type=Memory *` and get 15082496248 bytes for heap usage. When I do the same for Eden space with `get java.lang:name=G1\\ Eden\\ Space,type=MemoryPool *` I get 17968398336 for usage, which is larger than the whole heap. What am I doing wrong?